# How to Change the Color of Selected Content

Tags: css, css-selectors

Can anyone tell me how to change the color of the selected content??
em using this css for it

```
::selection {
        background: #ffb7b7; /* Safari */
        }
::-moz-selection {
        background: #ffb7b7; /* Firefox */
}
```

It works good but not what I want, it change the color of selected text but the spaces/gaps are not select, spaces/gaps are select with the default blue color, any remedy for it??
Check my Blog and try to select the spaces/gaps then u know exactly whats wrong with it..
Waiting for ur help :) http://kownleg.blogspot.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some areas that are highlighted in the darker blue colour, but I don't think there's much you can do about that if I'm being honest.

It actually looks like the ::selection pseudo element is supported experimentally by only a few browsers, and it doesn't look like it will be added to any others any time soon.  [See this link for more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/%3a%3aselection)